# Report Distance Between Two Turtles

Tags: netlogo

I have a model with two turtles, and the measurement of interest is the distance between them. I'd like to create a reporter that can be plotted that says simply that: the distance between the turtles. Can someone please help? I'm sure this is a simple thing, but I haven't been able to get it.

Thanks!

Comment: `[distance turtle 1] of turtle 0`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Alan

Comment: @Alan, I think you should make that an answer, even it is very short. This way, the answer can be accepted and question marked as answered. (Plus, you get rep!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Nicolas urges me to move this from comments to answers, you can retrieve the desired value with:

```
[distance turtle 1] of turtle 0
```